# A footer in React.js - Implementation suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the following set up:

[image: The set up]

- A navigation bar
- Very nested content, including a wizard and partial windows.
- A footer that is dynamic and it's buttons and their functionallity should be changed for part of the scenarios in the content.

For now, I implement it with a Footer's store that is modified like this:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setFooterButtons();
    //REST OF 'componentWillMount' CODE
}    
componentDidUpdate = () => {

    //If the uploading step is 'file-properties-editor'
    //then there is a view inside the view
    //that sets the footer buttons, in other cases,
    //the nested views does not change the footer's buttons
    //and they are defined here.

    if(this.state.uploadStep !== 'file-properties-editor'){
        this.setFooterButtons();
    }
    //REST OF 'componentDidUpdate' CODE
}

setFooterButtons = () => {
    footerActions.setFooterButtons([
        {
            fn: this.props.onBack,
            name: 'back',
            disabled: this.state.uploadStep === 'uploading'
        },
        {
            fn: this.onJump,
            name: 'jump',
            class: 'star'
        },
        {
            fn: this.onComplete,
            name: 'next'
        }
    ]);
}
```

The problem is that there are too many calls to store's 'setFooterButtons' from various places in various classes in the nested view.

Other things I tried was adding the footer as a component with buttons as property but it is very confusing as well when for example I have a view inside a view where the both of them shows different footer.

Answer (score 0):

For app state I would recommend an app store. Actions would trigger to set state. I attach the app store to the app control and pass appState props to the relevant components. An example from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxPages.

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';

let AppStoreObject = {
 appState: {currentPage: 'home'},
 init() { this.listenTo(Actions.appActions, this.onAppActions); },
 onAppActions(action) {
  switch (action) {
   case 'home':
   case 'about': this.appState.currentPage = action; AppStore.trigger(); break;
  }
 },

 getAppState() { return this.appState; }
}

const AppStore = Reflux.createStore(AppStoreObject);
export default AppStore;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

import AboutPage from './about/about.page';
import HomePage from './home/home.page';

import AppStore from '../flux/App.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

let allPageSty = {
 height: '100%',
 margin: '0',
 overflow: 'hidden',
 padding: '0',
 width: '100%'
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let page = this.state.appState.currentPage;
  let hideAbout = (page != 'about');
  let hideHome = (page != 'home');
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    <div id='allPageSty' style={allPageSty}>
     <AboutPage hide={hideAbout} />
     <HomePage hide={hideHome} />
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

let getState = function() { return {appState: AppStore.getAppState(),}; };

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount = () => { this.unsubscribe = AppStore.listen(this.storeDidChange); }
 componentWillUnmount = () => { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange = () => { this.setState(getState()); }
}
```